How to create rows combining data from two tables in a one-to-many relationship?
I have a table containing weather data by county:
CREATE TABLE weather (state_id TEXT, county_id TEXT, temperature REAL);

And a table containing one-to-many mappings between counties and zip codes (there are many zips per county). county_code in this table refers to the concatenation of state_id and county_id from the previous table.
CREATE TABLE zipcodes (county_code TEXT, zip TEXT);

How can I create a SELECT statement that maps zip codes to temperature? All zip codes in a county should get the same temperature. I am using BigQuery SQL. The tables are imported CSV, but I thought SQL-style CREATEs would be useful.
Not sure if this question belongs here or on DBA Stack Exchange, but here goes.

Can you share what your report out of your query should look like? I suppose, from what you say, that you expect, for example, for a zip code for Baton Rouge, Louisiana, something like: ----------> LA70801 | 32.1

@marcothesane I already got a working answer below, but yes, that is what I wanted, minus the LA.

I dont have google big query, but based on my understanding of the question I think you just need a CONCAT in the join condition,let me know.
Fiddle in Mysql
SELECT
    z.county_code,
    z.zip,
    w.temperature
FROM
    zipcodes z
INNER JOIN
    weather w
ON
    z.county_code = CONCAT(w.state_id, w.county_id);


This wasn't working, but it helped me figure out the solution and it would have worked if the data hadn't gotten messed up when I imported to BigQuery. +1

Turns out state_id and county_id got stored as strings, so concat didn't work as the leading zeroes on county_id were removed. I solved it by doing 1000*state_id + county_id, but the rest of your code worked. Thanks!
